# Inno setup edit xml file Without Change other data

Tags: inno-setup

this is My Xml

betas:

optIn: false

downloads:

altState: false ..>>>>>>>>  "How to change This **False** to **true** Using Inno Setup"

controlState: false

Please Help me

Comment: That's not XML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace a text in a file with Inno Setup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174359/replace-a-text-in-a-file-with-inno-setup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a sed function

```
// sed(file_to_edit, 'original_text', 'new_text');
function sed(fname: String; Orig: String; Moded: String): Boolean;
var
  fhandle: AnsiString;
  fhandle_uni: String;
begin;
  Result := LoadStringFromFile(WizardDirValue() + '\' + fname, fhandle);
  if Result = True then
  begin
    fhandle_uni := String(fhandle);
    StringChangeEx(fhandle_uni, Orig, Moded, True);
    Result := SaveStringToFile(WizardDirValue() + '\' + fname, AnsiString(fhandle_uni), False);
  end;
end;
```

WizardDirValue() is the installation dir, this will edit the file after finishing installation.

```
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurpageID = wpFinished then
  begin;
    sed('file.xml', 'altState: false', 'altState: true')
  end;
end;
```

or

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin;
    sed('file.xml', 'altState: false', 'altState: true')
  end;
end;
```

both should work.

Comment: sed("file.xml", "altState: false", "altState: true") >line get innosetup syntax error How to fix it and can i use it like this sed("{app}\file.xml", "altState: false", "altState: true") im use inno setup Unicode version please help. Link pic: http://imgur.com/a/TbGk2 .thank for your help.

Comment: You need to manually change _"_, when you copy from here is not the same.

Comment: Pascal does not use double-quotes. It uses single-quotes. Did you even try to compile the code?

Comment: thanks its worked .How to change WizardDirValue() Like   {userappdata}\Myapp\file.xml

Comment: `ExpandConstant('{userappdata}')+'\Myapp\'+fname`

Comment: Is this Correct Load String From File Command--> Result := LoadStringFromFileLoadStringFromFile('{userappdata}' + '\Myapp\file.xml' + fname, fhandle); I use this But Didnt work(Code compile Without error  But Didnt change data. please help me. thanks.

Comment: fname is an argument of sed function, so you should have "file.xml" in sed function but call sed function with "file.xml".