# Replace a string in a UTF-8 file without BOM in Inno Setup

Tags: utf-8, inno-setup, byte-order-mark

I need to change some values in a configuration file. The file is UTF-8 without BOM. I need to save it the same way. How do I do it with Inno Setup Unicode edition?

Note:

- [Replace a text in a file with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174359/replace-a-text-in-a-file-with-inno-setup) doesn't work
- and [Create a UTF8 file without BOM with Inno Setup (Unicode version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876001/create-a-utf8-file-without-bom-with-inno-setup-unicode-version) doesn't show how to read the file correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```pascal
const
  CP_UTF8 = 65001;

// ...
var
  FileName: string;
  S: string;
begin
  FileName := 'test.txt';
  if not LoadStringFromFileInCP(FileName, S, CP_UTF8) then
  begin
    Log('Error loading the file');
  end
    else
  if StringChangeEx(S, 'žluťoučký kůň', 'ďábelské ódy', True) <= 0 then
  begin
    Log('No value was replaced');
  end
    else
  if not SaveStringToFileInCP(FileName, S, CP_UTF8) then
  begin
    Log('Error writing the file');
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('Replacement successful');
  end;
end;
```

`LoadStringFromFileInCP` and `SaveStringToFileInCP` come from:
[Convert array of string to Unicode and back to ANSI in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46257538/850848)

*The code needs Unicode version of Inno Setup (the only version as of Inno Setup  6).

For Unicode string literals, your `.iss` file must be in UTF-8 encoding with BOM.*