# How to change LoadStringFromFile function from Inno Setup 5 to Inno Setup 6 and make it work

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, inno-setup-v6

I am trying to convert my code from Inno Setup 5 to 6. I can't make the following code work.

My old working code was:

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  FileData: String;
begin
  if (CurStep = ssInstall) then
  begin
    LoadStringFromFile(ExpandConstant('{code:GetSvcDir|2}\PostSteps.ps1'), FileData);
    StringChange(FileData, 'ScvProdPath', ExpandConstant('{code:GetSvcDir|0}\'));
    StringChange(FileData, 'ProdSitePath', ExpandConstant('{code:GetWebDir|0}\'));
    StringChange(FileData, 'ProdAuthPath', ExpandConstant('{code:GetWebDir|1}\'));
    StringChange(FileData, '444', ExpandConstant('{code:GetConfig|4}'));
    StringChange(FileData, '8732', ExpandConstant('{code:GetConfig|3}'));
    StringChange(FileData, 'RV_ExceptionsPath', ExpandConstant('{code:GetSvcDir|2}\RVExceptions'));
    SaveStringToFile(ExpandConstant('{code:GetSvcDir|2}\PostSteps.ps1'), FileData, False);
  end;
end;
```

I tried to change it after read some articles like this, but i can't make it work.

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  FileData: AnsiString;
  UnicodeStr: string;
begin
  if (CurStep = ssInstall) then
  begin
    LoadStringFromFile(ExpandConstant('{code:GetSvcDir|2}\PostSteps.ps1'), FileData);
    StringChangeEx(UnicodeStr, 'ScvProdPath', ExpandConstant('{code:GetSvcDir|0}\'), True);
    StringChangeEx(UnicodeStr, 'ProdSitePath', ExpandConstant('{code:GetWebDir|0}\'), True);
    StringChangeEx(UnicodeStr, 'ProdAuthPath', ExpandConstant('{code:GetWebDir|1}\'), True);
    StringChangeEx(UnicodeStr, '444', ExpandConstant('{code:GetConfig|4}'), True);
    StringChangeEx(UnicodeStr, '8732', ExpandConstant('{code:GetConfig|3}'), True);
    StringChangeEx(UnicodeStr, 'RV_ExceptionsPath', ExpandConstant('{code:GetSvcDir|2}\RVExceptions'), True);
    SaveStringToFile(ExpandConstant('{code:GetSvcDir|2}\PostSteps.ps1'), FileData, False);
  end;
end;
```

Text inside file is English, not something special. Could you please help me?

Comment: I've realized that I do not really understand the point of your question. Your original code should compile and work in Inno Setup Unicode/6 (with the same ASCII limitation as in Ansi/5). What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have commented to your previous question, this is not about upgrading from Inno Setup 5 to Inno Setup 6. Inno Setup 6 is compatible with Inno Setup 5 code. Your problem is that you have used legacy Ansi version of Inno Setup 5. And Inno Setup 6 has Unicode version only. You should have used Unicode version even with Inno Setup 5. 
See [Upgrading from Ansi to Unicode version of Inno Setup (any disadvantages)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43158677/850848)

In general, you should not use `AnsiString`. It's a legacy of the Ansi version. With `AnsiString`, your code will fail, if a user uses non-ASCII characters in the the paths.

So in the end, your question is more or less duplicate of:
[Inno Setup replace a string in a UTF-8 file without BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54333050/850848)

---

Anyway, to answer your literal question: You never assign the `UnicodeStr` variable.

Also as with your previous question: Do not use `ExpandConstant` to call a function.

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  FileData: AnsiString;
  UnicodeStr: string;
begin
  if (CurStep = ssInstall) then
  begin
    LoadStringFromFile(GetSvcDir('2') + '\PostSteps.ps1', FileData);
    UnicodeStr := FileData;
    StringChangeEx(UnicodeStr, 'ScvProdPath', GetSvcDir('0') + '\', True);
    StringChangeEx(UnicodeStr, 'ProdSitePath', GetWebDir('0') + '\', True);
    StringChangeEx(UnicodeStr, 'ProdAuthPath', GetWebDir('1') + '\', True);
    StringChangeEx(UnicodeStr, '444', GetConfig('4'), True);
    StringChangeEx(UnicodeStr, '8732', GetConfig('3'), True);
    StringChangeEx(UnicodeStr, 'RV_ExceptionsPath', GetSvcDir('2') + '\RVExceptions', True);
    FileData := UnicodeStr;
    SaveStringToFile(GetSvcDir('2') + '\PostSteps.ps1', FileData, False);
  end;
end;
```

*(untested)*

And you probably do not even need the functions then – you can inline them to the above code, unless you use them elsewhere.

You will also find [`AddBackslash` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_addbackslash) useful.

Comment: Always you! Thank you very much Martin. You really great.